# JS работа с JSON

Tags: javascript

Есть JSON вывод подобного содержимого:

```
{
   "code":0,
   "message":"hello",
   "detail":{
      "домен-1":{
         "user":"user-1",
         "http":"http->https",
         "unic_id":null
      },
      "домен-2":{
         "user":"user-2",
         "http":"https->http",
         "unic_id":null
      }
   }
}
```

и таких может быть несколько. Как мне правильно оформить цикл, чтобы можно было вывести список
в духе `alert(result["detail"]["домен-номер"]["http"]);` отдельно для каждого?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать **[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)** - метод возвращает массив собственных перечисляемых свойств указанного объекта в формате `[key, value]`, в том же порядке, что и в цикле `for...in`

```js
var test = {"code":0,"message":"hello","detail":{"домен-1":{"user":"user-1","http":"http->https","unic_id":null},"домен-2":{"user":"user-2","http":"https->http","unic_id":null}}};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(test.detail)) {
  console.log(`${key} ${value.http}`); 
}
```

Comment: огромное спасибо

Comment: @HELLOWORLD если ответ помог - можно ткнуть галочку напротив него :)

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.parse()](https://learn.javascript.ru/json#json-parse) преобразовывает json строку в обьект.

```js
var test = '{"code":0,"message":"hello","detail":{"домен-1":{"user":"user-1","http":"http->https","unic_id":null},"домен-2":{"user":"user-2","http":"https->http","unic_id":null}}}';

var myobj = JSON.parse(test);

console.log(myobj['detail']['домен-1']);
```